# fluentbit conf help for stacktrace in k8s logs

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, fluent-bit

I want to properly parse my pod logs to see stack trace as well using fluent-bit (1.8.7) and view them in Kibana if possible.

With the below configuration I'm able to get the stacktrace as a single log but they still seem to be in json format.

Any help is appreaciated, thanks.

**log I'm trying to parse**

```
10:49:24.539 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor - Reading to [somenamespace.service.data.SomeResponse<?>]
10:49:24.540 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: some message!
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: some message!
        at com.ui.configuration.SecurityConfiguration$2.authenticate(SecurityConfiguration.java:155)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:219)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:95)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at com.ui.configuration.SecurityConfiguration.lambda$configure$0(SecurityConfiguration.java:69)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
10:49:24.540 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
...
```

**fluent-bit conf** (running as configmap so clipped out those bits)

```
  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Flush         1
        Log_Level     info
        Daemon        off
        Parsers_File  parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server   On
        HTTP_Listen   0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port     2020

    @INCLUDE input-kubernetes.conf
    @INCLUDE filter-kubernetes.conf
    @INCLUDE output-elasticsearch.conf

  input-kubernetes.conf: |
    [INPUT]
        Name               tail
        Tag                kube.*
        Path               /var/log/containers/*.log 
        DB                 /var/log/flb_kube.db
        DB.Sync            Normal
        Docker_Mode        Off
        Docker_Mode_Flush  5 
        Key                msg
        Exclude_Path      /var/log/containers/*logging*.log,/var/log/containers/*kubebox*.log
        Multiline on
        Parser_Firstline   multiline
        Parser             docker
        Buffer_Chunk_Size  2MB
        Buffer_Max_Size    5M 
        Mem_Buf_Limit      100MB
        Skip_Long_Lines    Off 

  filter-kubernetes.conf: |
    [FILTER]
        Name                kubernetes
        Match               kube.* 
        Merge_Log           On 
        K8S-Logging.Parser  On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude On 
    
  output-elasticsearch.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name            es
        Match           *
        Host            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}
        Port            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
        Logstash_Format On
        Logstash_Prefix fluentbit_applogs
        Logstash_DateFormat %Y%m%d
        Replace_Dots    On
        Retry_Limit     False

  parsers.conf: |
    [PARSER]
        Name multiline
        Format regex
        Regex /(?<time>[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){1})(.+)(?<type>(\s(ERROR|DEBUG|INFO|WARN)\s){1})(?<message>.*)/
        # Command      |  Decoder | Field | Optional Action
        # =============|==================|=================
        Decode_Field_As   escaped_utf8    msg    do_next
        Decode_Field_As   json       msg 
        Time_Key  time
        Key_name    msg 

    [PARSER]
        Name        json
        Format      json
        Time_Key    time
        Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
        Key_name    msg

    [PARSER]
        Name        docker
        Format      json
        Time_Key    time
        Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
        Time_Keep   On
        Key_name    msg
        Decode_Field_As   escaped_utf8    log
```

**What I'm seeing in Kibana,** (in **message** field for some reason)

```
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: some message!\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540704772Z"}
{"log":"org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: some message!\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540762149Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at com.ui.configuration.SecurityConfiguration$2.authenticate(SecurityConfiguration.java:155)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540778673Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540791544Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:219)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540804382Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:95)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540816725Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540825917Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.54083466Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at com.ui.configuration.SecurityConfiguration.lambda$configure$0(SecurityConfiguration.java:69)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540843962Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540852739Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540861059Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540869302Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540877617Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540885816Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540894114Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540902458Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540922948Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540931909Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540940395Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540949084Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540957383Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540965668Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540973901Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540982039Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540990387Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.540998585Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541006741Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541014854Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541023235Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541031353Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541039614Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541047861Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541056065Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541064146Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.54107235Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541080476Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541088601Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541097474Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541105715Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541118824Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541127246Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541135361Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541143592Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541151765Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541159906Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541168142Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541176253Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2021-10-07T07:49:24.541184446Z"}
```